# How to Update a row with some declard and setted Values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, declare

Hi i struggle with my stored-procedure which adds 'NULL' instead of a number

**So why does the following procedure adds 'NULL' instead of a value between 0 and infinity?**

Here is my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Plan_Abschluss]

    -- My parameters for the stored procedure
    @date                   AS datetime2(7),
    @Einrichtung            AS Int,
    @Mitarbeiter            AS Int

AS
BEGIN

    -- declare my parameters
    DECLARE @PlanStunden            AS decimal(18, 2)= null,
            @PlanUrlaub             AS Int= null,

            @oldDate                AS datetime2(7)= null,
            @oldUrlaubskonto        AS Int= null,
            @oldStundenKonto        AS decimal(18, 2)= null;

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- set the previous month
    SET @oldDate= DATEADD(month, -1, @date);

    -- get some values from the previous row and set it to my parameters
    SELECT  @oldUrlaubskonto =  ISNULL(CurrentUrlaubskonto,0) ,
            @oldStundenKonto =  ISNULL(CurrentStundenKonto,0)

    FROM    [Plan]

    WHERE   [Jahr]              = YEAR(@oldDate)
    AND     [Monat]             = MONTH(@oldDate)
    AND     [RefMitarbeiterId]  = @Mitarbeiter
    AND     [RefEinrichtungId]  = @Einrichtung;

    -- get some values from the row i want to update and set it to my parameters
    SELECT  @PlanStunden =  ISNULL(PlanStunden,0) ,
            @PlanUrlaub =   ISNULL(PlanUrlaub,0)

    FROM    [Plan]

    WHERE   [Jahr]              = YEAR(@date)
    AND     [Monat]             = MONTH(@date)
    AND     [RefMitarbeiterId]  = @Mitarbeiter
    AND     [RefEinrichtungId]  = @Einrichtung;

    -- update the row and do a calculation with my parameters
    UPDATE  [Plan]

    SET     Abgeschlossen       = 1,
            CurrentUrlaubskonto = @oldUrlaubskonto+ @PlanUrlaub,
            CurrentStundenKonto = @oldStundenKonto+ @PlanStunden 

    WHERE   [Jahr]              = YEAR(@date)
    AND     [Monat]             = MONTH(@date)
    AND     [RefMitarbeiterId]  = @Mitarbeiter
    AND     [RefEinrichtungId]  = @Einrichtung

END
```

Comment: What values are being set to `NULL`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff CurrentUrlaubskonto  and CurrentStundenKonto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables will not be set in a `select` if no rows are returned.  My guess is that the first `select` using `@OldDate` simply doesn't match any rows.

In particular, the variables `@oldUrlaubskonto` and `@oldStundenKonto` are initialized to `NULL`, so they are never set, when there is no matching record.  One easy way to fix this is to use aggregation -- you are expecting one row anyway, so that is okay:

```
SELECT  @oldUrlaubskonto =  ISNULL(max(CurrentUrlaubskonto), 0) ,
        @oldStundenKonto =  ISNULL(max(CurrentStundenKonto), 0
```

You can also set the value afterwards, if it is still `NULL`.